# Indoor sliding doors now stick at the top after replacing rollers

Tags: doors

I have sliding doors for a wardrobe, and i replaced the roller-wheels.  Now they stick at the top, its as if they are too close together. I replaced the wheels in the same spot on the door, but they are slightly different brackets for the wheels, so I'm not sure if its just a matter of me trying to find the "sweet spot" to screw the wheel-bracket, or if its something else I should be looking at.

Comment: Any chance you can post a picture or two, showing how they are sticking?

Comment: i'll get a photo, they are rubbing together at the top because they are too close together, which I don't understand because I only put new rollers on.  cheers.

Comment: is it possible that the rollers are the wrong thickness or could they be on backwards?

Comment: Thanks @shirlock homes the rollers were a wrong thickness whic was part of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for everyone that asked questions.  There were a few things I had to change to finally get it working.  I had just bought the house and I assumed that the previous owner had the door's rollers fitted properly, basically I had to:

- Use the old wheels and brackets as the ones i purchased were not sticking out the same length
- The wheels were put on the wrong side of one of the doors
- The bottom guides were not screwed in the correct spot
- The wheels had to be adjusted as they were not the same height

Once all of these factors were fixed the door finally worked!